# Exception when trying to download file from google storage : "The specified data could not be decrypted"

Tags: c#, google-app-engine

I created Bucket on google Storage and I programmatically uploaded some files on it. When I try to download them, I get this exception:

> The specified data could not be decrypted

[image: Console Error]

I wrote code such that

```
GoogleCredential credential = null;
        var jsonFileBytes = Properties.Resources.stitcherautoupdate_55bd51f48cf0;
        var jsonFileString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(jsonFileBytes, 0, jsonFileBytes.Length);
        var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<System.Object>(jsonFileString);
        var jsonString = json.ToString();
        credential = GoogleCredential.FromJson(jsonString);
        StorageClient = StorageClient.Create(credential);
        StorageClient.DownloadObject(bucketName, fileName, fileStream);
```

Comment: Please share the logs where you can see the error in App Engine logs. From a first look it seems like either something is wrong with authentication, or your usage of json conversions is not proper. However, I need to see the logs to be able to investigate further.

Comment: i see exception on  this line  StorageClient.DownloadObject(bucketName, fileName, fileStream);

Comment: @Eliahu Aaron and also when i made bucket public i also can't download some files but public files i can downloaded it by System.Net.WebClient

Comment: Take a look at this documentation that shows exactly how you can properly download those files. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#storage-download-object-csharp If this does not work then most likely you are doing something wrong when uploading them. But to help you I need detailed info on how you are uploading, logs from GAE and Cloud Storage, and anything else that might give me more insight.

Comment: I Uploaded file by this method                                                                         public  void UploadFile(String bucketName, String path)
        {       
            var file = path;
            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open,
                FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
            {
                var fName = Path.GetFileName(path);
                Google.Apis.Storage.v1.Data.Object obj = this.StorageClient.UploadObject(bucketName, fName, "text/plain", fileStream);
                              
            }
        }

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation regarding your issue is to try following the methods for upload and download mentioned in the documentation. Once you get it working, you can start slowly changing the code so you know which part is the one causing the issue.

[This document](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries?hl=en#client-libraries-install-csharp) describes how you should first configure your Cloud Storage client library and setting up authentication.

A sample code for [uploading an object](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-code-sample):

```
private void UploadFile(string bucketName, string localPath,
    string objectName = null)
{
    var storage = StorageClient.Create();
    using (var f = File.OpenRead(localPath))
    {
        objectName = objectName ?? Path.GetFileName(localPath);
        storage.UploadObject(bucketName, objectName, null, f);
        Console.WriteLine($"Uploaded {objectName}.");
    }
}
```

For [downloading an object](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#storage-download-object-code-sample):

```
private void DownloadObject(string bucketName, string objectName,
    string localPath = null)
{
    var storage = StorageClient.Create();
    localPath = localPath ?? Path.GetFileName(objectName);
    using (var outputFile = File.OpenWrite(localPath))
    {
        storage.DownloadObject(bucketName, objectName, outputFile);
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"downloaded {objectName} to {localPath}.");
}
```